# How to deny EF update model from database for certain tables?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

Is there a way to tell EF not to update SSDL for the single table when doing `Update Model From Database`?

A little more details:
We're using EF 4.3 with Db-first approach (so, edmx and Update Model From Database).

We have a table that for some reasons does not have a primary key set in SQL Server, but have an auto-incremented `Identity` column that we can tell EF to use as primary key.

Since EF isn't finding any primary key in a table itself, it generates a DefiningQuery in SSDL for that table (and prevent update/inserts).

I can easily delete that DefiningQuery (and modify other EntitySet attributes) and everything works fine.

Except when I do another `Update Model From Database` that DefiningQuery is back again.

Is there a way to tell EF not to update SSDL for that single table?

Comment: Well, the **easiest** solution would be to give that table a primary key on that Identity column.... **ANY** "real" table ought to have a primary key.

Comment: That's kinda hard :) That real table does have a key (in mind): it is composite of 4 columns and some of them are nullable (EF doesn't like nulls within a key). So, we added a surrogate key for ease of use. But db is also populated and consumed by ERP service, and it doesn't know about that `Identity` field, so we can't make it a primary key. Idea of surrogate key worked well and really simplified few things, except for ssdl-regeneration..

Comment: **WHY** can't you make that surrogate column the primary key?? The purpose of the primary key is to uniquely identify each row - a surrogate `IDENTITY` does that perfectly well!

Comment: The reason is a little bit out of context :) Actually, there's a service that performs synchronizations of MsSQL db with ERP system, which has it's own "database". That service should know about all primary keys to associate them with ERP keys. But there's no that surrogate `Identity` in ERP and they do not need it. Modifying the synchronization procedure is unwanted at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell EF not to update SSDL for the single table when
>   doing Update Model From Database?

Not with default designer provided in Visual Studio. Once you modify SSDL part of your EDMX file you should maintain it manually or write a script which will fix it every time you run Update from database.

Alternatively you can buy more powerful designer or [extension to Visual Studio](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) which will offer you selective update.

Anyway what you are trying to do should be avoided. If the database is owned by ERP you should do the access only through ERP programming API (real ERP has some). Otherwise you can break functionality of your ERP, corrupt ERP data, cause performance issues or even cause deadlocks.

Comment: I know, I'm aware and I do use the api :) I also thought about integrating into .tt templates and correcting an ssdl manually, seems like a way to go. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: FWIW, the extension may not be an option for long:  **Important notice: This product will be discontinued on 31 Dec 2013. Existing licenses will still be valid, and can still be used in Visual Studio 2012, 2010, and 2008. However, new licenses will not be issued after this date.**